# inserting elements into array creates nested array where they aren't wanted

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm storing a post_meta_key in WP. The value is an array.

I do a get_post_meta - [which returns an empty array the first time](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).  `$single` is set to false. This array is called `$voters`, as it stores a list of voters. The key is the user id, the value is an array, described next.

Then I loop through the inputs, sanitize them, and create another key=>value array called the `current_vote`. This is the value set to the user id key.

I would like to insert the `current_vote` as a value into the voters array. Right now, I'm trying this:

```
$voters[$voter_id] = $current_vote;
```

This properly creates a key from the `$voter_id`, and put the `current_vote` array as the value.

BUT! as the second vote comes in, it doesn't just insert another key into the existing array - it takes that first vote, and inserts it into a NEW array!

The first vote looks like this:

```
    Array
           (
    [13] => Array
        (
            [13] => 0
            [15] => 75
            [21] => 0
            [34] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [50] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [45] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [40] => 0
            [41] => 0
            [52] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [29] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [30] => 0
            [48] => 0
            [53] => 0
            [38] => 0
            [35] => 0
            [61] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [62] => 0
            [54] => 0
            [49] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [42] => 0
            [55] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [46] => 0
            [56] => 0
            [32] => 0
            [36] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [44] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [57] => 0
            [37] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [51] => 0
            [31] => 0
            [43] => 0
            [47] => 0
            [39] => 0
        )
)
```

Once the second vote comes in, it looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [13] => Array
                (
                    [13] => 0
                    [15] => 75
                    [21] => 0
                    [34] => 0
                    [16] => 0
                    [50] => 0
                    [28] => 0
                    [45] => 0
                    [10] => 0
                    [40] => 0
                    [41] => 0
                    [52] => 0
                    [22] => 0
                    [29] => 0
                    [23] => 0
                    [30] => 0
                    [48] => 0
                    [53] => 0
                    [38] => 0
                    [35] => 0
                    [61] => 0
                    [26] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                    [62] => 0
                    [54] => 0
                    [49] => 0
                    [14] => 0
                    [19] => 0
                    [42] => 0
                    [55] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [12] => 0
                    [46] => 0
                    [56] => 0
                    [32] => 0
                    [36] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [17] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [27] => 0
                    [44] => 0
                    [25] => 0
                    [57] => 0
                    [37] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [51] => 0
                    [31] => 0
                    [43] => 0
                    [47] => 0
                    [39] => 0
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [13] => 75
            [15] => 0
            [21] => 0
            [34] => 0
            [16] => 0
            [50] => 0
            [28] => 0
            [45] => 0
            [10] => 0
            [40] => 0
            [41] => 0
            [52] => 0
            [22] => 0
            [29] => 0
            [23] => 0
            [30] => 0
            [48] => 0
            [53] => 0
            [38] => 0
            [35] => 0
            [61] => 0
            [26] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [62] => 0
            [54] => 0
            [49] => 0
            [14] => 0
            [19] => 0
            [42] => 0
            [55] => 0
            [5] => 0
            [12] => 0
            [46] => 0
            [56] => 0
            [32] => 0
            [36] => 0
            [2] => 0
            [17] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [27] => 0
            [44] => 0
            [25] => 0
            [57] => 0
            [37] => 0
            [3] => 0
            [51] => 0
            [31] => 0
            [43] => 0
            [47] => 0
            [39] => 0
        )

)
```

so, the element is inserted correctly (new element has key 4), but the first element is inserted into a new array key 0.

Here's my full code:

```
$quarter = substr($date, 1,1);
$year = substr($date, 2,4);

$voters = get_post_meta(2165, 'bonus_votesq'. $quarter . $year);

//initialize vote arrays and vars
$votes = $_POST['votes'];
$voter_id = $_POST['voter_id'];
$voting_array = array();
$current_vote = array();
parse_str($votes, $voting_array);

foreach ($voting_array as $vid => $awarded_points) {
  $current_vote[sanitize_key($vid)] = sanitize_key($awarded_points); 
}

// push the local array into what will be the global array
$voters[$voter_id] = $current_vote;

//if meta_data doesn't exist, update_post_meta creates one. if it does, it updates it.
update_post_meta(2165,'bonus_votesq'. $quarter . $year, $voters);
echo print_r($voters);
```

What is going on?

Comment: Do the variables $voter_id and $vid *both* mean "the current voter id number"? Does the function sanitize_key() sanitize keys, values, or both?

Comment: You should `var_export($voters, true)` immediately after `get_post_meta`, so that you can see what you're getting back each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the post meta data and putting them back onto the same array, `$voters`. You should either assign the `$voter_id` ahead of time and use it as the key before you use `post_meta_data`, or use a different variable to store it.

If you mean use `$voter_id` as a key ahead of time, have you tried this:

```
//initialize vote arrays and vars
$quarter = substr($date, 1,1);
$year = substr($date, 2,4);
$votes = $_POST['votes'];
$voter_id = $_POST['voter_id'];
$voting_array = array();
$current_vote = array();

$voters[$voter_id] = get_post_meta(2165, 'bonus_votesq'. $quarter . $year);

parse_str($votes, $voting_array);

foreach ($voting_array as $vid => $awarded_points) {
    $current_vote[sanitize_key($vid)] = sanitize_key($awarded_points); 
}

// push the local array into what will be the global array
$voters[$voter_id] = $current_vote;

//if meta_data doesn't exist, update_post_meta creates one. if it does, it updates it.
update_post_meta(2165,'bonus_votesq'. $quarter . $year, $voters);
echo print_r($voters);
```

Comment: This line isn't what i want: $voters[$voter_id] = get_post_meta(2165, 'bonus_votesq'. $quarter . $year); - what i want is the full list of users (into array $voters), and then i want to insert a new key/value into $voters. if i do this, it will insert the array of ALL the voters into one key only - the $voter_id key.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like you are pulling the post(Form) data into `$voters`, reformatting it, and putting it back into `$voters`?

Comment: close. i'm pulling existing data into $voters, preparing new data in $current_vote fro the post['votes'], and inserting new data back into $voters.

Comment: What does the `print_r($voters)` look like just after `get_post_meta()` is called for the second vote?

Answer (score 0):

I got it! The question Jason asked - what does $voters look like just after get_post_meta sent me on the right track -

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

if $single is set to false, which it was - get_post_meta return an ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY, with my results inside it. so, that's where the extra array came in. since i was inserting my new votes in there, it now had the associative array AND my new vote.